# Qual a diferença entre o .on('input') / .on('paste') / .on('change')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validação

Eu estava tentando fazer uma validação porém com o *.on('input')* ele funciona melhor do que o *.on('paste')* (eu precisei colocar um timeout para que ele funcionar), alguém pode me explicar a diferença entre os dois? Segue o meu código para ilustrar a pergunta:

**paste**

```
$(this).on("paste", "#email", function(event) {
        var $obj = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                var str  = $obj.val();
                $obj.val(str.replace(/[^a-za-uA-ZA-U0-9_@\.\'\b\t]/g, ''));
            }, 2);
        });
```

**input**

```
$(this).on("input", "#email", function(event) {
        var $obj = $(this);
                var str  = $obj.val();
                $obj.val(str.replace(/[^a-za-uA-ZA-U0-9_@\.\'\b\t]/g, ''));
        });
```

**change**

```
 $(this).on("change", "#email", function(event) {
            var $obj = $(this);
                    var str  = $obj.val();
                    $obj.val(str.replace(/[^a-za-uA-ZA-U0-9_@\.\'\b\t]/g, ''));
            });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O evento `input` é mais genérico e dispara por exemplo com `paste` ou eventos de teclado. O `paste` é mais específico e não dispara quando escreves com o teclado.

O `paste` irá disparar primeiro e depois o `input`.

Outro evento genérico é o `change`, que funciona como o input basicamente mas não dispara logo. Por vezes só quando o input perde o foco.

Podes testar aqui:

```js
$('input').on('change paste keyup input', function(e) {
  console.log(e.type, this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: A quem deu o `-1` convido a motivar para perceber o que pode estar errado na minha resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Então a diferença é simples o `on-input` só é chamado quando introduzes algum valor, e o `on-paste` só será chamando ao colares um valor <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>

Da uma olhada neste exemplo básico:

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  console.log('change ' + this.value);
});

$('input').on('input', function() {
  console.log('input ' + this.value);
});

$('input').on('paste', function() {
  console.log('paste ' + this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A diferença básica é que o [*oninput*](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/event_onpaste.asp) é disparado sempre que o usuário entra com qualquer valor no campo, enquanto que o [*onpaste*](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/event_onpaste.asp) é apenas quando o usuário *"cola"* alguma informação.